# get arguments from a url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I dont know much about htaccess and haven't found a solution for this issue.

I want that if a user opens example.com/**@username**/**posts** a php file is displayed and the username and page type (e.g. /posts/) is availiable as a get argument.

I already found this: `RewriteRule "^user/([A-Z a-z 0-9_\-.]{1,})((/\w+)+|/?)$" "/account/profile.php?name=$1"`  but this isn't my usecase because its example.com/user/username

Do you know how to realise example.com/**@username**/**posts** orexample.com/**@username**/**images** with my htaccess or other stuff?

Thanks a lot, I am a newbie in this area :D
Have a great sunday!

Comment: What can characters can the username contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule "^@([\w.]+)\/(.+)$" "/account/profile.php?name=$1&page=$2"
```

1. `^` and `$` make it so that the expression in-between must try to match everything, not a sub-string.
2. `([\w.]+)` matches and captures uppercase, lowercase, 0 to 9, underscore (_), hyphen **and dot (the dot might not be required in your case, in which case you can change it to `(\w+)`)**. `+` makes it greedy (matches as much as possible).
3. `(.+)` matches and captures as much a possible.

Comment: You can simply use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_\-]`. "w" stands for "word character". Shortcuts like `\w` and `\d` are _much_ easier to read in a regular expression. The additional dot (".") you specified in the character class is not captured by `\w`, but it is not required here anyway. And you did not mention it in your description anyway.

Comment: @arkascha nice catch there. I agree. But isn't the dot required here? It is used is a lot of places for usernames in this world.

Comment: That is something only the OP can answer. It depends on what form a "username" can take _in this specific situation_ ... If the dot is required, then you still can use `[\w.]` ...

Comment: @arkascha ... Thanks for reminding me about that. I totally forgot `\w` could be used inside those. It is better to ask the author indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The username consists of letters, numbers and dots so \w. should do the job.